# Control - C exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, copy-paste

I need to catch that exception but I can't figure out which one it is. The IDE i'm using right now doesn't allow for a program interrupt that way.

I know how to user try/catch, but I don't actually know what I'm trying to catch..

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall that CTRL-C becomes an InterruptedException and this [article](http://www.esus.com/docs/GetQuestionPage.jsp?uid=392) seems to support that. As suggested in other answers the use of `addShutdownHook` is a good way to go, unless you want to prevent the shutdown.

Comment: while addShutdownHook() worked, I the InterruptedException was more general so I used it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that InterruptedException only is thrown from things like sleep/wait. If you have a main thread just executing custom logic, it will not throw InterruptedException. When you send an interrupt to a thread (not a process, a thread), it sets a boolean which sleep/wait checks and throws InterruptedException. To catch Ctrl-C, you have to use Signal.handle or addShutdownHook.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

> Registers a new virtual-machine
>   shutdown hook.
>
> The Java virtual machine shuts down in
>   response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or
>     when the exit (equivalently,
>     System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user
>     interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a
>     system-wide event, such as user logoff
>     or system shutdown.

I'm not sure if you can actually *catch* it as such, you just supply a `Thread` to be run when the VM is shutting down. I don't think you can stop it once this kicks off.

Answer (score 0):

addShutdownHook() is what you want.

http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/javalang/trapctrlc.html